# React app on digitalocean droplet axios requests not working on other machines

Tags: reactjs, nginx, webserver, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

Hey all I'm having an issue pulling up my website on my desktop. On my laptop where I created the app and did all the code my React app works fine and updates however on other machines only my components/elements load while my axios requests are returning (404 connection refused error). Any tips or fixes? P.S This is my first time trying to deploy an app build to a webserver (digitalocean/NGINX).

NGINX config file

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/epenn92reactapp.space/html/among-us-reactapp3/client/buil>
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name epenn92reactapp.space www.epenn92reactapp.space;

        error_page 405 =200 $uri;
        error_page 404 /index.html;

        location ^~ /assets/ {
                gzip_static on;
                expires 12h;
                add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

        location /v1/api {
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://64.227.5.159:8080;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/epenn92reactapp.space/fullchain.pem; >
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/epenn92reactapp.space/privkey.pem>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

    server {
        if ($host = www.epenn92reactapp.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        if ($host = epenn92reactapp.space) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name epenn92reactapp.space www.epenn92reactapp.space;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Example axios Route

```
    const [chars, setChars] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/character', {
        });
        setChars(res.data)
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log('error', err)
      }
    };
    fetchData();

  }, [chars.length]);
```

Server.js file

```
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
```

package.json

```
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"
```

I've been reading around for about a day now and I'm just not sure what to do any help would be great thanks!